# How and where to allocate memory? 

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I narrowed down my problem to not allocating memory properly. I have a NSMutableArray called subjects as a member of a Category.  When I populate the category with the array of subjects it doesn't store.

I am not sure how and where to allocate the memory for subjects, which is what I believe my problem is.

Here is the snippet:

```
    Category *cat = [[Category alloc] init];
    cat.category_title = [result_categories stringForColumn:@"CATEGORY"];

    QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    for (Subject *sb in appDelegate.subjects){

        if([cat.category_title isEqualToString:sb.category_title]){
            [cat.subjects addObject:sb];
            NSLog(@"Adding subject: %@ cat.subjects.count=%i", sb.title, cat.subjects.count);

        }

    }
```

(The above log does print cat.subject names but it doesn't print the subjects.count)

Comment: What is the size of appDelegate.subjects?

Comment: 151 is the size of appDelegate.subjects

Comment: Does your app actually print `Adding subject: ...` when you run it?

Comment: Also, try `NSLog("cat.subjects = %@", cat.subjects)`.  Does it print an array?  Or does it print `(null)`?

Comment: It doesn't print any array.  It prints (null)

Comment: It does print adding subject:...

Comment: possible duplicate of [I set an NSDate, then it comes back null right away. Any ideas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369973/i-set-an-nsdate-then-it-comes-back-null-right-away-any-ideas)

Comment: and I'll say what I said there: Inspect `cat` and `cat.subjects`. Are they what you expect them to be?

Comment: Thanks Josh and I read your other post.  cat is what I think it is and subjects is not.  I edited my original post to get the exact question answered that looks like my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you allocate memory to `cat.subjects` like

```
cat.subject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

or

```
subject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in your `Category` class ? if not then do it. This might be the one of the problem.

---

**Update**

first of all change your code from `Category *cat = [Category alloc];` to `Category *cat = [[Category alloc] init];`

and change your init as

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        subjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Do check that array is allocate memory,this might be one of the reason  that any objects are not getting added in it.

Comment: I think this is probably the problem.  I am not allocating memory to it anywhere.  I added this:  - (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    
    subjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    if (self) {
        // Initialize self.
    }
    return self;
}
 and tried it again and it did same thing.

Comment: your line:  Category *cat = [Category alloc];  should read Category *cat = [[Category alloc] init]; or the routine you just added won't get called.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that but it still didn't work.  I think it is what Inder Kumar said but I just don't know where I am supposed to do that in the code.